# Need help to click Watir Web driver button

Tags: watir-webdriver

I have the HTML as

```
<li>
  <div data-track="discovered_spots" data-filter="discovered_spots" class="button filter-button">
    <span class="icon-compass"></span>
      Discoveries (2)
  </div>
</li>
```

I am trying to click the button link

```
@browser.div(:class =>'button filter-button').span(:text => ' Discoveries (2) ').click
```

Just not working or producing any errors.

I have also tried using the xpath

```
 #@browser.div(:xapth => "//div[@data-track='discovered_spots']").click
 #@browser.div(:text => "Discoveries").click
```

but that produce errors.

I have also viewed and tried the code present in other questions chains but none worked any help will be very useful.

Comment: The best possible solution to such a query where you are not able to click the button is to check the @browser.url addition and goto the appended url. Well this trick did worked for me.... Thanks!

Comment: Are those typos in your "also tried" section? Because ":xapth" wouldn't work, and your matching :text string would be "Discoveries (2)" and not just "Discoveries".

Comment: Oh, no those are not typos, in case of "Discoveries" alone I was actually trying to overcome the regular expression as using the double quotes was not allowing \(\d*\). I need regular expression because the digit can be any starting from 1.

Comment: If you use `:xapth` as a locator, that should throw an error (i.e. `MissingWayOfFindingObjectException`). And a regex to match on "Discoveries (2)" should look something like this: `browser.div(:text => /Discoveries \(\d+\)/).click`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@browser.div(:text, /Discoveries/).click
```

Regex for the attribute should hit the text. Not specifying \d anchor will cast a wider net in case that value of 2 fluctuates by only looking for the match of Discoveries in text and ignoring the number and parentheses.